# Flex3 'transportsession' Webservice Session Management with Axis2?

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, flex3, session-cookies, apache-axis

I am building a prototype hybrid app with a Flex3 RIA client and backend Axis2 in Java on Tomcat 6. As this is a prototype, and given that I keep options open for factoring in other client types, I'm using a plain old SOAP service between client and server, rather than any Flex-specific technologies like BlazeDS

Although there is much debate about the need for stateful behaviour on the backend for an RIA, I need to consider the possibility of maintaining transport-level sessions between client and server. From reading the docs for both Axis2 and Flex, this appears to involve

(a) setting scope="transportsession" in services.xml, and
(b) ?what? in Flex

Can anyone help with (b)?

The webservice client classes are being generated in Flex Builder using the WDSL introspection wizard, so unless I refactor this, I only have access to the methods thus exposed.

I have found zero examples of the above online, and the FLex documentation leaves something to be desired in this area.

All help appreciated.

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bit old article . but may be useful.
transportsession : This session is managed using transport cookies, and the lifetime is equal to the lifetime of the underline transport.

http://wso2.org/library/2060